# How to incorporate my own feature functions into Mallet CRF?

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, mallet, crf

I am implementing my own CRF model, and I want to use Mallet's CRF trainer to get weights for the feature functions I implemented.

How can I pass my feature functions to Mallet's CRF, so that it would search for their optimal weights?